# How can I pass Hidden Field value with CommandArgument of LinkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one `Repeater` with multiple rows.each row has one LinkButton and one HiddenField.
HiddenField value is bind at time of Repeater's Event `OnItemDataBound`.

My Question is that How can I pass this `HiddenField` Field Value with `CommandArgument` of this LinkButton?

Following is my source code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptServiceRequestList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptServiceRequestList_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptServiceRequestList_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCustomerDeposit" runat="server" Text="Pay Deposit" CommandName="DepositFees" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ServiceRequestId") %>'>
       </asp:LinkButton>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hidAmount" runat="server" />
</asp:Repeater>
```

Please Help me. thank you to all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set multiple command argument or the another way is you can use `FindControl("hidAmount")` method of repeater .

- You can use below code.

  `HiddenField hdnAmount  = (HiddenField)rptServiceRequestList.FindControl("hidAmount");
      int amnt = Convert.ToInt32(hdnAmount.Value);`

Comment: @Dens Please click upvote or click 'correct' if above answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple command argument(to send hidamount along with command Argument) as:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCustomerDeposit" runat="server" Text="Pay Deposit" CommandName="DepositFees" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ServiceRequestId") + "|" +Eval("HidAmount")%>'
   </asp:LinkButton>
```

And on ItemCommand:

```
 protected void rptServiceRequestList_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
 {        

  string[] arg = new string[2];
  arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|'); // Split Here to seprate CommandName And Hidden Value
  string YourcommandName = arg[0]; // Your Command Name
  string YourHiddenValue = arg[1]; // Your Hidden Field Value

}
```